# Longest palindrome in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python assignment which wants me write a program that finds the longest palindrome in a given text. I know there are examples of this function in other languages on this website, but I am a total beginner in Python and am having trouble writing the code.

This is how I am currently identifying palindromes:

```
def is_palindrome(word):
    x = 0 
    for i in range (len(word)/2):
        if (word[x]) == (word[len(word)-x-1]):
            x+=1
        if x == (len(word)/2):
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: It seems to be the longest common subsequence problem for the inputs ``text`` and ``reversed(text)``. The LCS is well-studied, and there are numerous implementations in many languages, including Python (for example, [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_subsequence#Python)). Unless by palindrome you mean a separate word, not a chunk of text.

Comment: @fjarri Yes, I think this question is actually not as complicated as an LCS problem, it seems that it's word-based, although more information from OP about example input would help make that clearer.

Comment: `max((word for word in text.lower().split() if word[::-1] == word), key=len)`

Comment: @Marius, so it seems to be a LCS problem after all :)

Comment: He also wants the code to return palindromes within words like "racecar" will return "aceca"

Answer (score 6):

Alternate way

```
def Is_palindrome(word):
       return word==word[::-1]
# Assuming text is defined
print max((word for word in set(text.split()) if Is_Palindrome(word)), key=len)
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down voting. I will try to improve.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. This should be a comment instead. Also, it is not down voted, it has a positive number of votes!

Comment: @jakeminds, How it is not answering the question. Are you not getting the answer?

Comment: Quote from the question: "I have a Python assignment which wants me write a program that finds the longest palindrome in a given text."

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
def Is_palindrome(word):
    x = 0 
    for i in range (len(word)/2):
        if (word[x]) == (word[len(word)-x-1]):
            x+=1
        if x == (len(word)/2):
            return True
    return False

def longest_palindrome(text):
    lst = text.split() #Split it into words (cannot have punctuation)
    palindromes = [] #List that contains the palindromes
    long_len = 0 #Length of the longest palindrome
    longest = "" #The actual longest palindrome
    for i in lst: #Loop through all the words
        if Is_palindrome(i): #If the word is a palindrome
            palindromes.append(i) #Add it to the palindrome list
    for i in palindromes: #Loop through the palindrome list
        if len(i) > long_len: #If the palindrome is longer than the longest one
            longest = i #Set it as the longest one
            longest_len = len(i) # Set the length of the longest one to the length of this one
    return longest
```

Comment: @TerribleCoder007 Did you want it to return palindromes if they are in the middle of the word?

Answer (score 1):

```
def fastLongestPalindromes(seq):
    seqLen = len(seq)
    l = []
    i = 0
    palLen = 0
    while i < seqLen:
        if i > palLen and seq[i - palLen - 1] == seq[i]:
            palLen += 2
            i += 1
            continue
        l.append(palLen)
        s = len(l) - 2
        e = s - palLen
        for j in range(s, e, -1):
            d = j - e - 1
            if l[j] == d: 
                palLen = d
                break
            l.append(min(d, l[j]))
        else:
            palLen = 1
            i += 1
    l.append(palLen)
    lLen = len(l)
    s = lLen - 2
    e = s - (2 * seqLen + 1 - lLen)
    for i in range(s, e, -1):
        d = i - e - 1
        l.append(min(d, l[i]))

    return l
def getPalindrome(text):
    lengths = fastLongestPalindromes(text)
    start = 0
    end = 0
    length = 0
    for i in range(len(lengths)):
        if(lengths[i] > length):
            length = lengths[i]
            end = i//2+(lengths[i]//2)
            start = i//2-(lengths[i]//2)
            if(i%2 == 1):
                start +=1
    return text[start:end]
```

In linear time. (longer code, but faster than the other answers, atleast for long strings).

Source: http://www.akalin.cx/longest-palindrome-linear-time (first function is copy pasted)

Comment: This is a really old question, but are you sure this runs in linear time? You have two nested loops with variables i and j, so it should be O(n^2)

Comment: @fafl Unfortunately calculating the complexity of a program isn't as simple as counting the maximum amount of nested for loops. Please read the linked article for clarification. Especially the comments in the code about loop invariants should help you convince yourself it is indeed linear.

Comment: The link didn't work when i wrote my earlier comment, now I see how it runs in O(n)